# Selected text action as Word AddIn in C#

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, office-2007

I'd like to have a Word 2007+ AddIn (in C#) which after selecting text and the right mouse click shows a pop-up menu with MY OWN Item and after clicking this Item I can use the selected text as string in the event handler.

Please, I am completely new to the AddIn development. How to do that two things?

Comment: hi if u dont mine please give the your working code, i have very urgent to complete the task what you are posting question is the same in my task

Comment: Don't have the code anymore. Look at the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you prefer VBA or C#? Both are viable options. I will say however, VBA is a more lightweight solution. A good VBA example can be found
[here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=20650&page=1) and a beautiful C# example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47cs5caa%28VS.80%29.aspx). Hope that helps.